# How to mix Qt and native iOS user interface elements in a single App?

Tags: ios, qt, uikit, qml, qwidget

I'm using Qt 5.2 for iOS.

I'd like to mix QtQuick 1.1 or QWidgets with native iOS user interface elements in a single app.

Embedding a qml view into a UIView, having to switch to another window, embedding a UIView into a qml component, any help in that direction is welcome !

Answer (score 2):

Coming a bit late, it is possible to show a native UIView on top of the Qt universe.
The technique for embedding an UIView is letting the UIView "float" over an in-hierarchy QWidget and update the UIView's geometry whenever the geometry of the in-hierarchy widgets changes. The limitation for this: you can't simply place such a widget inside a QTabWidget (then you need additional code for hiding/showing the UIView). Also QMainWindows being raised over the QMainWindow containing the UIView won't work.

```
class View : public QWidget
  ...
  private:
    UITextView* m_TextView;
    bool m_scheduled;
```

implementation

```
View::View(QWidget* parent):QWidget(parent),m_Scheduled(false)
{
    m_TextView=[[UITextView alloc] init];
    QWidget* w= window();
    UIView *parentView = reinterpret_cast<UIView *>(w->winId());
    [parentView addSubview:m_TextView];
}
View::~View()
{
    [m_TextView removeFromSuperview];
    m_TextView=nil;
}
bool View::event(QEvent* e)
{
    if (e->type()==QEvent::Move || e->type()==QEvent::Resize) {
      if (!m_scheduled) {
        m_scheduled=true;
        QTimer::singleShot( 0, this, SLOT( updateGeo() ) );
      }
    }
    return QWidget::event(e);
}
static inline QRect globalRect(QWidget* widget)
{
    return QRect((widget)->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)), (widget)->size());
}
void View::updateGeo()
{
    m_scheduled=false;
    QRect rg=globalRect(this);
    QRect rw=globalRect(window());
    CGRect cg=CGRectMake(rg.x(), rg.y()-rw.y(), rg.width(), rg.height());
    [m_TextView setFrame:cg];
}
```

The complete sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/leopatras/UITextView-on-Qt).
Another approach is using a QML viewer and qmlRegisterType to register a QQuickItem descendant.

```
qmlRegisterType<MyTextView>("MyTextView", 1, 0, "MyTextView");
```

header

```
class MyTextView : public QQuickItem
   ...
   private:UITextView* m_view;
```

in the implementation the geometryChanged method is overriden to compute the new rectangle in UIView coordinates

```
static inline CGRect toCGRect(const QRectF &rect)
{
  return CGRectMake(rect.x(), rect.y(), rect.width(), rect.height());
}
MyTextView::MyTextView(QQuickItem *parent /*= 0*/)
    : QQuickItem(parent)
    , m_view(0)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(windowChanged(QQuickWindow*)), this, SLOT(onWindowChanged(QQuickWindow*)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(visibleChanged()), this, SLOT(onVisibleChanged()));
}

MyTextView::~MyTextView()
{
    [m_view release];
}
void MyTextView::onWindowChanged(QQuickWindow* window)
{
    if(!m_view) {
        m_view = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    }
    if (window != 0) {
        UIView *parentView = reinterpret_cast<UIView *>(window->winId());
        [parentView addSubview:m_view];
    } else {
        [m_view removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
void MyTextView::geometryChanged(const QRectF &newGeometry, const QRectF &oldGeometry)
{
    QQuickItem::geometryChanged(newGeometry, oldGeometry);
    CGRect rc = toCGRect(mapRectToScene(newGeometry).toRect());
    rc.size.width -= 2;
    rc.size.height -= 2;
    [m_view setFrame:rc];
}
void MyTextView::onVisibleChanged()
{
    [m_view setHidden:isVisible()];
}
```

and in the qml file

```
...
import MyTextView 1.0

Window {
    visible: true

    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 5
        spacing: 5

        Rectangle {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            height: 100
            border.width: 1
            border.color: "red"
            color: "#cccccc"

            MyTextView {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The complete sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/seyedmmousavi/Native-UITextView-on-Qt-KDAB).

Comment: Hi Leo! I've just started to play with Qt. There is a desktop app which has been done in it and I wonder if there is a way to reuse some of UI elements built in Qt for an iOS app. Would it be possible to somehow extract UI controls done in either QML or pure C++ and use them in an iOS app?

Comment: @matthewfx Your question is a bit vague. My understanding is that you ask to embed a Qt widget (hierarchy) in a native IOS widget . I can't really answer this, it might be perhaps possible. In any case this requires an intimate knowledge of Qt's IOS intrinsic implementation. I don't believe that there is an official IOS equivalent to QMacNativeWidget http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmacnativewidget.html (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867731/how-to-use-qmacnativewidget-in-ios).

Comment: Thanks @Leo, Looks like in the meantime another developer in our team with more experience in C++ has figured it out.

Comment: @mattewfx Interesting! If you don't mind sharing your knowledge you could ask your question as a separate new stackoverflow question and your team mate could earn some points...:-)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible right now and in near future.

Qt doesn't support native UI for iOS and Android right now.Qt widgets are drawing in opengl context. Qt app is like full-screen game for iOS.

[More info](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/35197).