# How to use QMacNativeWidget in IOS

Tags: ios, qt

I am trying to make an UIView with QWidget subview from Qt IOS SDK. I found, that QMacNativeWidget may do the thing, but its constructor accepts Cocoa'a NSView, not UIView. How can it be done in IOS?

Comment: Well, it's `QMacNativeWidget`, not `QIosNativeWidget`.

Comment: But is there QIosNativeWidget?

Answer (score 0):

QMacNativeWidget is for apple's AppKit -- OS X. There is currently no equivalent for UIKit -- iOS.